# Building a simple command to traverse X steps toward the root

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

In windows, I had a batch simple script in my path that I could type "up 3"
and it would call "cd .."  3 times.

"up.bat"

```
@echo off                         
if (%1)==() (                     
    cd ..                         
) else (                          
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%1) do (   
        cd ..                     
    )                             
)
```

How do I do the same in linux/bash scripting? The below doesn't lead to the directory changing

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(eval echo {1..$1})
do
   cd ..
done
```

Comment: Put the function in your startup scripts.  eg, in `$HOME/.bashrc`, add the line `up() { local i=${1-1}; while test $((i--)) -gt 0; do cd ..; done; }` or `up() { for (( i=${1-1}; i > 0; i-- ));  do cd ..; done; }` or similar.

Comment: or, you can source your script instead of executing it.  If you run `./myscript`, (where myscript is the file you show above), the script does cd up, but it is running in a subshell so it doesn't affect your shell.  OTOH, if you run `. myscript`, the `cd`s will happen in the current shell and you will notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of the below, which includes both how to enact on non subshell and also how to make it a raw command

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for (( i=0; i<$1; i++ ))
do
    cd ..
done
$SHELL
```